# Rebind the view and append the div in knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I, have a question and answer in the below format. First answer of question 4 has the QuestionReference Question 5.on load of page i want to append the question 5 below the answer of question 4.

[image: Question references]

Below is the HTML code

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $data.QuestionsSet">
                                    <div class="primaryCaseContainer" data-bind="attr: {id: $data.Id } , visible: $data.Available, toplevel: $data.TopLevel, css: TopLevel? 'avalable': 'notavailable'">
                                        <p class="questionHeader">
                                            <span data-bind="text: $data.DisplayValue+'.'"></span>
                                            <span data-bind="html: GetEditListGuidelineQuestion.HtmlReplace($data.HtmlText)"></span>
                                        </p>
                                        <div data-bind="attr:{id: 'colapseID'+$data.Id }" class="questionContainer">

                                            <div data-bind="foreach: $data.AnswersSet">

                                                <!--ko if:$parent.Type == 2 -->
                                                <div data-bind="attr:{class: $parent.Id +' marginTopTbl'}">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr:{id: $data.Id , Qid: $parent.Id , Qref: $data.QuestionRefSetStrings , Uid: $data.Uid , rel: $data.MutuallyExclusive ? 'true' : 'false'} ,checked: $data.Selected, click: $root.answerClick">
                                                    <span data-bind="html: GetEditListGuidelineQuestion.HtmlReplace($data.HtmlText)"></span>
                                                    <span><b data-bind="text: $root.findQuestionref($data.QuestionRefSet)"></b></span>
                                                    <!--ko if:$data.InputType == "text" -->
                                                    <input type="text" data-bind="if: Selected, textInput : $data.Value, attr:{id: $data.Id , name:$parent.Id,  Qid: $parent.Id, Qref: $data.QuestionRefSetStrings , Uid: $data.Uid}">
                                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                                    @Html.Partial("_MCGSubQuestionPartial")
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- /ko -->
                                                <!--ko if:$parent.Type == 1 -->
                                                <div data-bind="attr:{class: $parent.Id +' marginTopTbl'}">
                                                    <input type="radio" data-bind="value: $data.RadioOnly, attr:{id: $data.Id , name:$parent.Id,  Qid: $parent.Id, Qref: $data.QuestionRefSetStrings , Uid: $data.Uid}, checked: $data.Selected , click: $root.answerClick , appendQrefQuestion: {Qref: $data.QuestionRefSetStrings, parentAndOwnID: $data.Id+$data.QuestionRefSetStrings}">
                                                    <span data-bind="html: GetEditListGuidelineQuestion.HtmlReplace($data.HtmlText)"></span>
                                                    <span><b data-bind="text: $root.findQuestionref($data.QuestionRefSet)"></b></span>
                                                    <!--ko if:$data.InputType == "text" -->
                                                    <input type="text" data-bind="if: Selected , textInput: $data.Value , attr:{id: $data.Id , name:$parent.Id,  Qid: $parent.Id, Qref: $data.QuestionRefSetStrings , Uid: $data.Uid}">
                                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                                    @Html.Partial("_MCGSubQuestionPartial")
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- /ko -->
                                                <div data-bind="foreach: $data.QuestionRefSet">
                                                    <div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 10px" data-bind="attr:{id :'showAns' +$parent.Id+ $data.Id , class:'subQuestion showAns' +$parent.Id+ $data.Id}, if: $data.QuestionRefSetStrings != null"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
```

The knockout code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttonPOCBack").hide();
    $("#PlanOfCareModal").hide();
    ko.applyBindings(GuidelineQuestion, document.getElementById("GuidelineQuestionAnswers"));
    GuidelineQuestion.GetGuildlineQuestion();

    ko.bindingHandlers.appendQrefQuestion =
        {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                if (value.Qref != "") {
                    $('#' + value.Qref).appendTo('#showAns' + value.parentAndOwnID);
                }
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                if (value.Qref != "") {
                   $('#' + value.Qref).appendTo('#showAns' + value.parentAndOwnID);


                }
            }
        };
});
```

The problem is onbinding the DIV is not formed so append code  wont be work. I want to rebind the element and append the references question.

I try lots of things but not able to find the solution can anyone please help me to do this.

Comment: What does the `GuidelineQuestion` object (your viewmodel) look like?

Comment: Are you trying to show Q5 when user answers Q4? We really should see your ViewModel. But you are pretty much still thinking like you are in jquery environment. In knockout you shouldn't care about manipulating the DOM, but you should care about your observables in your ViewModel and leave DOM manipulation to knockout bindings.

Comment: I agree with @Azadrum. You should add Q5 to the `QuestionsSet` array. It if is an observable array the foreach binding will automatically render Q5 when it is added to the array.